# Remove background color of directory when displaying ls

Tags: zsh, ls

I have this issue where some directory are colored [image]

I'd like to keep the color but remove the background (here in green but it can be sometimes an other color)
I'd like to remove background colored.

I'm using zsh terminal on MacOS Monterey 12.1.

I already found other post about this but none of them are working for me

Comment: Note that zsh is not a terminal emulator let alone a terminal. It's just a shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's colouring done by `ls`, not `zsh` (though `zsh` can be configured to colour files the same way as GNU `ls` does in its completion listings).

Here, green background with blue foreground is the colour you get in the default configuration of GNU `ls` with `--color` (not FreeBSD `ls`, which should be the `/bin/sh` of macos) for directories that don't have the sticky bit and are writable by *others* (than the owner and group-owner).

If some directory has those permissions, that usually means there's a problem. It's way too lax. So it's a good thing that you get an annoying colour, as that would be an insentive for you to fix it.

`dircolors -p` shows the default configuration:

```
$ dircolors -p | grep -w -e 34 -e 42
# 30=black 31=red 32=green 33=yellow 34=blue 35=magenta 36=cyan 37=white
# 40=black 41=red 42=green 43=yellow 44=blue 45=magenta 46=cyan 47=white
DIR 01;34 # directory
STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE 30;42 # dir that is sticky and other-writable (+t,o+w)
OTHER_WRITABLE 34;42 # dir that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
```

(34 being the code for foreground blue, 42 for background green in ANSI colouring escape sequences).

STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE (black on green) will match on world writable directories like `/tmp`. But those are not as bad as the OTHER_WRITABLE in that at least users (other than the directory owner) can't delete / rename the files they don't own.

To change those defaults, you'd redirect that output of `dircolors -p` to some file:

```
dircolors -p > ~/.config/dircolors
```

Edit it to your taste. For instance change the OTHER_WRITABLE to something even more outrageous and unbearable:

```
OTHER_WRITABLE 5;48;5;210;38;5;47 # some shade of green on some shade of pink
                                  # background and blinking to urge users
                                  # to fix the permissions
```

(here using escape sequences typically recognised by terminal with 256 colour palette support; the initial 5 for blinking is ignored by many terminals these days as its too annoying).

You'd add to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.config/dircolors)"
```

For those settings to be loaded into the `$LS_COLORS` environment variables, where that `OTHER_WRITABLE 5;48;5;210;38;5;47` would show up as `ow=48;5;210;38;5;47`.

For `zsh` to show the same colours in its completions, you'd need at least (after the line above in `~/.zshrc`):

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
```

Though you'd likely want to do a proper tuning via `compinstall`, where walking through the menus will lead you to:

```
3.  Styles for changing the way completions are displayed and inserted.
```

➡️

```
3.  Configure coloured/highlighted completion lists, selection of items
    and scrolling.
```

➡️

```
1.   Use coloured lists for listing completions.
```

➡️

```
1.  Using the default colours.
2.  Using the colours already set up for GNU ls via the $LS_COLORS
    environment variable.  Note this must be set before the completion
    configuration code is executed.
3.  Turn colouring off.
```

Where selecting 3 ➡️ 3 ➡️ 1 ➡️ 3 would add that `zstyle` line above to your `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Thx for your answer ! Didn't worked on MacOSX but worked on Linux shell.
For MacOS i used this:
```export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExQxBxDxCxegedabagExEx```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

First check what your `ls` really is by using `which ls`, in my case, it was aliased to be `gls --color=tty`, which was not set by myself but rather zsh or ohmyzsh

Simply `unalias ls` will remove the background color

If you want to keep the text foreground color, just alias `ls` to `ls -G` or something else